# Appropriate SIP response for status code 477 when SIP proxy isnt able to reach endpoint

Tags: sip, freeswitch, sip-server

In an implementation, I am running into a case when freeswitch is acting as proxy. It generates 477 as the dispatcher server ahead is down , since i wasnt able to find 477 in sip draft anywhere I assumed to keep the reason as "Send Failed"( based on ref : http://opensips-open-sip-server.1449251.n2.nabble.com/SIP-2-0-477-Send-failed-477-TM-Route-td7595929.html). Not sure if it is as per standard supported across carriers . Any documentation for sip 477 response will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

All official rfc defined responses are listed at **iana.org**, the *Internet Assigned Numbers Authority*.

You can find the list [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/sip-parameters/sip-parameters.xhtml#sip-parameters-7)

rfc3261 definitly allows any application (or new rfc) to extend SIP and use a new code. It also allow to use any self-defined Reason for the response codes you defined as well as the pre-defined response codes...

From rfc3261, about **reason phrase**: [Section: 7.2 Responses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-7.2)

> While this specification suggests specific wording for the reason
> phrase, implementations MAY choose other text, for example, in the
> language indicated in the Accept-Language header field of the
> request.

From rfc3261, about **status-code**: There is no restriction in usage of *status-code* in the BNF of SIP.

See [Section 25  Augmented BNF for the SIP Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-25)

```
Status-Code     =  Informational
               /   Redirection
               /   Success
               /   Client-Error
               /   Server-Error
               /   Global-Failure
               /   extension-code
extension-code  =  3DIGIT
```

The important part above is *extension-code  =  3DIGIT* which means any 3 digit number can be used (of course, from 100 to 699 only).

PS: 477 is a specific code seen in kamailio, opensips, ser, openser family which, if I'm correct, usually indicate an error with the transport layer.

Comment: thanks , I added a generic custom response for 477 based on section7.2 as you suggested